# Cocoa Dynamic List in NSMenu

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nsmenu

Looking at OS X's built-in applications, such as the WiFi and Bluetooth assistant, they seem to have a list that can be dynamically changed.
[image]
However, I cannot seem to change the menu without destroying and recreating it (i.e. adding and removing at an index). I am not convinced that this is the best way. Is there a better way to achieve this in Swift?

Comment: Have you tried using the `NSMenu` methods for adding and removing menu items?

Comment: @JWWalker That's what I meant by destroying and recreating.

Comment: There are `NSMenuItem` methods for changing the title, state, and image.  Are those not sufficient?